# SQL - Date Between (xxxx-06-21 and xxxx-09-21)

Tags: mysql, sql, search

How is it possible to use the BETWEEN function in MySQL, to search for dates in ***any*** year but between a specific day/month to a specific day/month? Or if it's not possible using BETWEEN, how else could I accomplish it?

To be more descriptive, I am trying to add a seasonal search to my photo archive website. So if a user chose to search for "summer" photos, it would search photos taken between 21 June and 21 September, but from any year.

If Carlsberg made SQL, I think it would be :)

```
WHERE date BETWEEN 'xxxx-06-21' AND 'xxxx-09-21'
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution given elsewhere, `WHERE date.MONTH() || date.DAY() BETWEEN '0621' AND '0921'`, is a good one (and it's well worth upvoting since it's fine for most MySQL databases) but I'd like to point out that it (and most queries that involve per-row functions) won't scale that well to large tables.

Granted, my experience is that MySQL is not used that often for the sizes where it would make a huge difference but, in case it is, you should also consider the following.

A trick we've used in the past is to combine extra columns with insert/update triggers so that the *cost of calculation* is only incurred when necessary (when the data changes), rather than on every select.

Since the vast majority of databases are read far more often than written, this amortises that cost over all selects.

For example, add a new column `CHAR(4)` called `MMDD` and whack an index on it. Then set up insert/update triggers on the table so that the `date` column is used to set this new one, based on the formula already provided, `date.MONTH() || date.DAY()`.

Then, when doing your query, skip the per-row functions and instead use:

```
WHERE MMDD BETWEEN '0621' AND '0921'
```

The fact that it's indexed will keep the speed blindingly fast, at the small cost of a trigger during insert/update and an extra column.

The cost of the trigger is irrelevant since it's less than the cost of doing it for every select operation. The extra storage required for a column is a downside but, if you examine all the questions people ask about databases, the ratio of speed problems to storage problems is rather high :-)

And, though this technically "breaks" 3NF in that you duplicate data, it's a time honoured tradition to do so for performance reasons, if you know what you're doing (ie, the triggers mitigate the "damage").

Comment: That's a very informative answer, thank you. Yes, my table contains 100,000+ rows and growing fast, so performance is essential. I've already combined some of my photo, keywords and events tables, in to one table, to allow full-text indexing to run smoother - so I am very familiar with de-normalizing DB's. I will test this tomorrow to see how it goes, thanks again. I hope one day there will be a built in function for this...

Answer (score 3):

I'd think the easy way is to take the dates, turn them into strings, take the postfix, and run it through the `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE date.MONTH() || date.DAY() BETWEEN '0621' AND '0921'
```

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution, so +1, but you should be aware that it (and probably any _other_ solution) may seriously degrade your performance.

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting for the clever solution, too.. just wanted to toss the obvious solution out there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution bdares, and thanks for the suggestion paxdiablo... performance is critical, I have over 100,000 photos and growing fast. I will have to test it thoroughly before deciding to apply it, just curious how I can actually achieve this using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

the `RIGHT` function may help

```
select
    current_date,
    right(current_date,5),
    right(current_date,5) between '06-21' and '09-21' `IsTodaySummer？`,
    '09-21' between '06-21' and '09-21' `Is 09-21 Summer？`;
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| current_date | right(current_date,5) | IsTodaySummer？ | Is 09-21 Summer？ |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| 2011-09-29   | 09-29                 |               0 |                 1 |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

but as ajeal said, add another column is better to use index.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to have this format of search,
I guess is better to break the date column into two,

- `year int(4) unsigned` (which is the year)
- `month_day int(4) unsigned` (which is mmdd)

build a composite index on `month_day, year`,
the idea is make index work better

example query like

```
where month_day between 621 and 921 -- make use on index
```

another example

```
where year=2011 and month_day between 900 and 930 -- make use on index too
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be an equivalent of Oracle's to_date() function in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the dates apart with the [`month`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`day`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) functions:

```
where month(date_column) between 6 and 9
  and if(month(date_column) = 6 and day(date_column) < 21, 0, 1)
  and if(month(date_column) = 9 and day(date_column) > 21, 0, 1)
```

The [`if`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) stuff is only needed because your boundaries don't line up nicely with the months.

If you're going to be doing a lot of this sort of thing then you might be better off precomputed the month-day version of the full date so that you can index it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need the year, subtract it from the date.
In MySQL, you can do something like this:

```
select * from some_table
where date_sub(date_col, interval year(date_col) year)
between '0000-06-21' and '0000-09-21';
```